# How to free the heap memory allocated for String class member without deleting the object

Tags: c++, string, heap-memory

I have a class `BLEValue` that has a member called `m_accumulation` of type `String`. I use this member to accumulate the data (15000 byte) received over bluetooth until the whole data is received and then this `m_accumulation` will be read and the data it saves is no longer needed therefore it is set to `""`.

```
void BLEValue::addPart(uint8_t *pData, size_t length)
{
    log_v("Adding part to m_accumulation. Current free heap: %d", ESP.getFreeHeap());
    m_accumulation += std::string((char *)pData, length);
}

void BLEValue::clear()
{
    m_accumulation = "";
    m_accumulation.clear(); // I think it does the same as the previous line
}
```

The problem is that the memory allocated in the heap for this class member will not get free again after emptying `m_accumulation`. I can check this using the function `ESP.getFreeHeap()`. I think this is so because the object of the `BLEValue` class is still alive and therefore the heap memory allocated for it will be not be freed until the object is killed. Is it true?

Is there a way to empty the heap memory allocated to this `String` after reading its value without deleting the `BLEValue` object completely?

Comment: *The problem is that the memory allocated in the heap for this class member will not get free again after emptying m_accumulation* -- The heap manager will just reuse that memory for further allocation requests.  What if that code is called a thousand times?  Will you accept the slowness of physically having the memory allocated/deallocated thousands of times?  That's why the heap manager exists, so that this doesn't occur.

Comment: In addition, many modern CPUs have a memory management unit that offers [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). This allows the system to push unused memory into a slower form of storage to free up faster memory for a task that needs that memory right now. Very cool stuff. Sometimes you'll find that objects your program holds don't have real storage assigned to some or all of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Clear marks the string as having size 0, but the internal array is not necessarily changed. To force the string to free it's memory, use [shrink_to_fit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit) after clear.

Comment: *To force the string to free it's memory,* -- There is no guarantee that `shrink_to_fit` will free the memory.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem. @PaulMcKenzie Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Salahuddin Write your own allocator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The allocator has no control over what memory the string class requests and when it releases it. If one is not happy with the implementation of `std::string`'s resource management, one needs to write their own `std::string` implementation. (That said, typically it can be "tricked" by e.g. swapping with an empty string.)

Comment: @user17732522 -- Not only write a string class, but make sure that whatever allocation routines you use are ones that use the operating system's heap allocation functions.